# I need to iterate xml missing end tags?

Tags: java, xml

```
 // Logic
     XMLInputFactory factory = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        Reader fileReader = new FileReader("1.xml");
        XMLEventReader reader = factory.createXMLEventReader(fileReader);

        while (reader.hasNext()) {
          XMLEvent event = reader.nextEvent();
          if (event.isStartElement()) {
            StartElement element = (StartElement) event;
            System.out.println("Start Element: " + element.getName());

            Iterator iterator = element.getAttributes();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
              Attribute attribute = (Attribute) iterator.next();
              QName name = attribute.getName();
              String value = attribute.getValue();
              System.out.println("Attribute name/value: " + name + "/" + value);
            }
          }
          if (event.isEndElement()) {
            EndElement element = (EndElement) event;
            System.out.println("End element:" + element.getName());
          }

          if (event.isCharacters()) {
            Characters characters = (Characters) event;
            System.out.println("Text: " + characters.getData());
          }
        }
```

Here this sample xml file

```
    <Bank>
          <Account type="saving">
                <Id>1001</Id>
                <Name>Jack Robinson
                <Number>7898998
                <Amt>10000</Amt>
          </Account>
    </Bank>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java 7:

```
Path xmlPath = Paths.get("1.xml");
byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(xmpPath);
String xml = new String(bytes, StandardCharSets.ISO_8859_1);
xml = xml.replaceAll("^\\s*<(\w+)[^>]*>[^<]+$", "$0</$1>");
StringReader stringReader = new StringReader(xml);
XMLEventReader reader = factory.createXMLEventReader(stringReader);
```

This intends to replace lines containing a single tag, followed by something.

I have added the encoding explicitly. Leaving it out, yields the current platform encoding, as with your FileReader. `StandardCharSets,UTF_8` in general is appropiate for XML, and you could check that: it is the default unless `<?xml ... encoding="..." ... ?>`.

---

For older Java:

```
File file = new File("1.xml");
int size = (int) file.length();
byte[] bytes = new byte[size];
FileInputStrea in = new FileInputStream(file);
in.read(bytes);
in.close();
String xml = new String(bytes, "ISO-8859-1");
```

The rest is the same; Exceptions to catch.

Comment: Eggen i acpt your answer but can you describ how to write java 1.4? is it possible?

Comment: @Suresh the soon coming Java 8 is so wunderfull; I hope you'll be able to switch in 2014.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$sxe = simplexml_load_string("your XML code here!!");
if ($sxe === false) {
  echo "Failed loading XML\n";
  foreach(libxml_get_errors() as $error) {
     echo "\t", $error->message;
  }
}
?>
```

Refer this tutorial from Jenkov
http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-xml/stax-xmleventreader.html

Comment: hey i already tried it... but i want to know can we possible to iterate the missing end tag in particular xml file?